# Why [(ngModel)] breaks all template in angular 4?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

This is my first component in angular. Here it is:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class Hero{
    id:number;
    name:string;
}

const HEROES: Hero[]=[
  {id:11,name:'Mr. Nice'},
  {id:12,name:'Arco'},
  {id:13,name:'Gillette'},
  {id:14,name:'Celeritas'},
  {id:15,name:'Magneta'},
  {id:16,name:'RubberMan'},
  {id:17,name:'Dynama'},
  {id:18,name:'Dr. Iq'},
  {id:19,name:'Magma'},
  {id:20,name:'TOrnado'}
];


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>{{title}}</h1>
            <h2>My heroes</h2>
            <ul class="heroes">
                <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" (click)="onSelect(hero)">
                    <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
                </li>
            </ul>
            <h2>Details of {{selectedHero.name}}</h2>
            <div><label>Id: </label>{{selectedHero.id}}</div>
            <div>
                <label>Name: </label>
                <input [(ngModel)]="selectedHero.name"/>
            </div>

  `,
  styles: [`

`]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  heroes = HEROES;
  selectedHero: Hero;

  onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
    this.selectedHero = hero;
  }
}
```

I deleted `styles` element because its big.
My template doesn't bind `heroes` array, When I use this in `template` element:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="selectedHero.name"/>
```

But when I delete above input, all `heroes` from array are correctly displayed in a `<ul>` list.

Why is it?

Comment: Is your module importing `FormsModule` ? Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: Yes, all works ok when I delete [(ngModel)] directve.

Comment: What do you mean by "break"? If you didn't include `FormsModule` in your angular module you should see an error. The only issue I see is that, maybe, the selectedHero is declared but it's undefined (it's defined as a type, but has no value, hence you should use an *ngIf or so)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because Angular can't read `selectedHero.name` while there is no selected hero. You can (and need to) show this input only when you have `selectedHero` using `*ngIf` directive, like this:

```
<input *ngIf="selectedHero" [(ngModel)]="selectedHero.name"/>
```

And not only for `input` - for every element where you're using `selectedHero`:

```
<h2 *ngIf="selectedHero">Details of {{selectedHero.name}}</h2>
<div *ngIf="selectedHero"><label>Id: </label>{{selectedHero.id}}</div>
<div *ngIf="selectedHero">
  <label>Name: </label>
  <input [(ngModel)]="selectedHero.name"/>
</div>
```

Or better add a wrapper with one `*ngIf` directive:

```
<div *ngIf="selectedHero">
  <h2>Details of {{selectedHero.name}}</h2>
  <div><label>Id: </label>{{selectedHero.id}}</div>
  <div>
    <label>Name: </label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="selectedHero.name"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

I remember, it was written somewhere in "Tour of Heroes" for Angular, it's not just my thoughts ;)

Answer (score 2):

You do not set `selectedHero` property, but still you try to display and modify it. Move hero details to section and add `ngIf` to it to display it only when it's set:

```
<div *ngIf="selectedHero">
    <h2>Details of {{selectedHero.name}}</h2>
    <div><label>Id: </label>{{selectedHero.id}}</div>
    <div>
        <label>Name: </label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="selectedHero.name"/>
    </div>
</div>
```